# how to show highlighting arrows like in Coderush

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms

I am programming winforms using c# and vb.net.

I love the arrows used in coderush.

for those who have not seen coderush arrows ,please see this image.

[image: http://www.aspnetpro.com/productreviews/2004/08/asp200408bn_p/asp200408bn_p_image002.jpg]
<sub>(source: [aspnetpro.com](http://www.aspnetpro.com/productreviews/2004/08/asp200408bn_p/asp200408bn_p_image002.jpg))</sub>

`http://www.aspnetpro.com/productreviews/2004/08/asp200408bn_p/asp200408bn_p_image002.jpg`

I want to have something similar in my program.
only difference is i will be using it to highlight textboxes and buttons.

I only want the arrow , the text on the arrow is not important.

So maybe I need to make a general function like
DrawHighlightArrow(controlname)

and it will somehow manage to draw an arrow  next to that control

Please suggest a nice geeky way to solve this problem in C# or Vb.net

Thank you

Anna

Comment: With what UI technology are you working? Please clarify by re-tagging and mentioning in your question.

Comment: Hello Kent , 
I am making a winform application. I have both VS2005 and VS2008.
I use both c# and vb.net

Answer (score 1):

Override the OnPaint method on the Form, and use the [DrawImage()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/42807xh1.aspx) method on the object from the PainteEventArgs.Graphics property to draw a bitmap of an arrow.

Comment: This begs the question: *which* graphics object? The arrow is likely to visually span several controls. I believe that was at the heart of this question.

Comment: Does that comment apply to the latest revision (501829) of my answer?

Comment: The problem here could be that the paint area occupied by textboxes and buttons might not be drawable in the paint handler(clipped children)/or will be erased/repainted by those children.

Comment: It might be necessary to subclass the textbox control.

Answer (score 1):

You *could* create a custom form with a transparent background, paint your arrow on it using GDI+ (using marxidad's technique above, or by just dropping a PictureBox on it and handling the Paint event).

Then just instantiate a new instance of the arrow form over the top of your existing "parent" form (you might want to set TopMost to true) and start a Timer to fade it out.

The only thing to be careful of there is...

- cleaning up properly if you prematurely close the "parent" form, and...
- passing through any click events to the "parent" form.

Answer (score 1):

There is a really nice library called Locus Effects [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/locuseffects.aspx).  Go check it out, it does exactly what you want it to do.